# Best web environment for running python powered website

Tags: web-development, webserver, python

I am new into python programming. 1st is was a php developer. Learnt php by poking around the internet. now in my collage course most of the course are based on python or java. So i thought to Get myself into python.
As i am new into python web development i noticed that there are many ways to do this job like doing CGI code, use mod_python in apache , use a MVC framework like Django  etc.
As i developed a php chatting server for my collage usage it received more then 1000 page requests per second. 
Now i want to convert my php project into a python website.
So, What technology should i use? Which one is more fast? Secure? 
Please tell me which one to use and explain me why?

Answer (score 0):

for a chat server in python, i'd look into [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/) -- it's probably going to be the most performant option.  it's event-driven, and supports the protocols you'll need out of the box.  i'd be surprised if there's a better choice than this.